# How does one go about proving (A&B)⊃C |- A⊃(B⊃C)?

Tags: logic

I am relatively new to logic and deductive reasoning, so this problem has been giving me some trouble.

I want to start with an assumption of (A&B) and try to isolate a subproof where I can then get B⊃C through a conditional introduction, but I keep getting stuck in my subproofs and unable to reason out of them.

Any hints and demonstrations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is scope for many such demonstrations depending on the framework you're using!  Do you have a set text that you're working from?

Comment: Damn, these symbols are implications and not subsets. Damn.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming A&B will get you something of the form (A&B)⊃... which is not what you want. Instead, to derive A⊃... you want to start with assuming A.

It should go something like this.

```
1. (A&B)⊃C        premise
2. | A            assumption
3. | | B          assumption
4. | | A&B        2,3
5. | | C          1,4
6. | B⊃C          3,5
7. A⊃(B⊃C)        2,6
```

Comment: Indeed.  In a Conditional Proof, one *assumes* the antecedant of the **conclusion**, and aims to derive the desired consequent.  Basically, @MoIsStillHere : start from the finish and work your way backwards.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to start with an assumption of (A&B) and try to isolate a subproof where I can then get B⊃C through a conditional introduction, but I keep getting stuck in my subproofs and unable to reason out of them.

Indeed, you will not get far with assuming the antecedant of the *premise*.

Given (A&B)⊃C and assuming (A&B), will allow you to derive C, and from that B⊃C may be derived (assume B, restate C, discharge).  However discharging the assumption of (A&B) therfore allows you to deduce,.. (A&B)⊃(B⊃C) from the premise.  So close, but no good.

But looking at that should have shown you where you went wrong and indicate what to do.

---

In a Conditional Proof, one *assumes* the antecedant of the **conclusion**, and aims to derive the consequent.  Basically: start from the finish and work your way backwards.

Okay.  So you seek to derive A⊃(B⊃C) from (A&B)⊃C .  Thus you should assume A aiming to derive B⊃C.  To do that, you should assume B aiming to derive C.

```
 |_ (A & B) ⊃ C        by premise. 
 |  |_ A                 by assumption.
 |  |  |_ B                by assumption. 
 |  |  :   
 |  |  :  
 |  |  |  C                we hope .  
 |  |  B ⊃ C             by discharging assumed B with conditional introduction.
 |  A ⊃ (B ⊃ C)        by discharging assumed A with conditional introduction.
```

Now how might you derive C ?

Well, it is time to use the *premise*.  To derive C from (A&B)⊃C you will also need (A&B).  We're okay.  This can be derived from the assumptions.

Thus:

```
 |_ (A & B) ⊃ C        by premise. 
 |  |_ A                 by assumption.
 |  |  |_ B                by assumption. 
 |  |  |  A & B            by conjunction introduction. 
 |  |  |  (A & B) ⊃ C      by restating the premise 
 |  |  |  C                by conditional elimination (modus ponens) .  
 |  |  B ⊃ C             by discharging assumed B with conditional introduction.
 |  A ⊃ (B ⊃ C)        by discharging assumed A with conditional introduction.
```

---

Now, can you do the converse?  Prove A ⊃ (B ⊃ C) entails (A & B) ⊃ C.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof agrees with the lines in [Eliran H's answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/56451/29944), but it provides the justification.

The OP has the following concern which I would like to address by explaining how not to get stuck in the subproofs:

> I want to start with an assumption of (A&B) and try to isolate a subproof where I can then get B⊃C through a conditional introduction, but I keep getting stuck in my subproofs and unable to reason out of them.

Here is the result using Klement's proof checker. Note that I am using "∧" rather than "&" and "→" rather than "⊃" so that I have well-formed formulas recognizable by the proof checker I am using. Also the inference rules are those the proof checker accepts. You may be required to use some different terminology:

[image]

On line 1 is the premise: "(A ∧ B) → C"

Because I will have two conditionals, rather than assuming "(A&B)", I will break this up into two subproofs, one assuming "A" and the other assuming "B". This will allow me to get two conditionals.

I start the first subproof on line 2. Note how the subproof is indented in this style of presentation. I immediately start the second subproof on line 3. At this point I have both "A" (line 2) and "B" (line 3) and so I can combine them with conjunction introduction (∧I) on line 4.

This is the first line of the proof that was not a premise nor an assumption. I need to provide a justification for it. That justification is given by "∧I 2, 3". Those symbols mean I am using conjunction introduction on lines 2 and 3.

Since line 4 is the premise needed to get "C" on line 1, I can use modus ponens or conditional elimination (→E) as the proof checker I am using requires me to call it and reference lines 1 and 4 for the justification.

At this point I can close the subproof starting on line 3. This discharges the assumption on line 3. I assumed "B" and reached a line that has "C" on it so I can write on line 6 "B→C" which, if you think about it is just another way of writing that subproof--if I assume "B" then I can derive "C".

Note that I can now do the same thing for the subproof starting at line 2 and ending at line 6 again using conditional introduction.  When I do that I get the desired result. The proof checker notes this with an acknowledgement that the proof is correct.

For more information about these particular rules see *forall x*. The link to the proof checker provides directions for how you may use it to check your other proofs.

---

Reference

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/